# BC30057: To many arguments

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The problem suddenly appeared and I have no clue why the problem appeared and how to fix it.

**Compilation Error**

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** BC30057: Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New(ItemNo As String, POLineMatch As String, ItemNumberPartCode As String, QuantityInvoiced As String, UnitPriceInvoiced As String, ExtendedPrice As String, ItemTax As String, Notes As String)'.

**Here is the code:**

```
Partial Class Plugins_NonPO_GLCoding
  Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim ItemNo As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("ItemNo"))
                Dim POLineMatch As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("POLineMatch"))
                Dim ItemNumberPartCode As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("ItemNumberPartCode"))
                Dim QuantityInvoiced As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("QuantityInvoiced"))
                Dim UnitPriceInvoiced As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("UnitPriceInvoiced"))
                Dim ExtendedPrice As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("ExtendedPrice"))
                Dim GLAccount As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("GLAccount"))
                Dim ItemTax As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("ItemTax"))
                Dim Notes As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("Notes"))
                Dim ItemTaxCode As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("ItemTaxCode"))
                Dim Department As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("Department"))
                Dim ShipToCode As String = Me.NullCheck(Me.InvoiceItemsDV.Table.Rows(i)("ShipToCode"))
                Me.InvoiceItems.Add(New InvoiceItems(ItemNo, POLineMatch, ItemNumberPartCode, QuantityInvoiced, UnitPriceInvoiced, ExtendedPrice, GLAccount, ItemTax, Notes, ItemTaxCode, Department, ShipToCode))
            Next
        End If
End Sub
End Class

Public Class InvoiceItems
    Private _ItemNo As String
    Private _POLineMatch As String
    Private _ItemNumberPartCode As String
    Private _QuantityInvoiced As String
    Private _UnitPriceInvoiced As String
    Private _ExtendedPrice As String
    Private _GLAccount As String
    Private _ItemTax As String
    Private _Notes As String
    Private _ItemTaxCode As String
    Private _Department As String
    Private _ShipToCode As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal ItemNo As String, ByVal POLineMatch As String, ByVal ItemNumberPartCode As String, ByVal QuantityInvoiced As String, ByVal UnitPriceInvoiced As String, ByVal ExtendedPrice As String, ByVal GLAccount As String, ByVal ItemTax As String, ByVal Notes As String, ByVal ItemTaxCode As String, ByVal Department As String, ByVal ShipToCode As String)
        Me._ItemNo = ItemNo
        Me._POLineMatch = POLineMatch
        Me._ItemNumberPartCode = ItemNumberPartCode
        Me._QuantityInvoiced = QuantityInvoiced
        Me._UnitPriceInvoiced = UnitPriceInvoiced
        Me._ExtendedPrice = ExtendedPrice
        Me._GLAccount = GLAccount
        Me._ItemTax = ItemTax
        Me._Notes = Notes
        Me._ItemTaxCode = ItemTaxCode
        Me._Department = Department
        Me._ShipToCode = ShipToCode
    End Sub
    Public Property ItemNo() As String
        Get
            Return Me._ItemNo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._ItemNo = value
        End Set
    End Property
' There are too many get sets so i deleted them out and left one for example
End Class
```

Everything worked properly and even on my duplicate machine everything works how it should work, what would be the reason for this error to pop up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you constructors are not the same:

```
From error: Public Sub New(ItemNo As String, POLineMatch As String, ItemNumberPartCode As String, QuantityInvoiced As String, UnitPriceInvoiced As String, ExtendedPrice As String, ItemTax As String, Notes As String)
From code:  Public Sub New(ByVal ItemNo As String, ByVal POLineMatch As String, ByVal ItemNumberPartCode As String, ByVal QuantityInvoiced As String, ByVal UnitPriceInvoiced As String, ByVal ExtendedPrice As String, ByVal GLAccount As String, ByVal ItemTax As String, ByVal Notes As String
                           , **ByVal ItemTaxCode As String, ByVal Department As String, ByVal ShipToCode As String**)
```

I guess you will have to clean your solution before recompiling. If it is not working, find all dll you have compiled on the machine and remove them from your machine. There is probably a dll which is not correctly cleaned. Or possibly the code you are showing is not the cause of your error.

Comment: There is no solution, it's separate file as plug-in and is compiled at run time, it couldn't be a different file. I will check if there is no ILLEGAL character.

Comment: @skmasq, in case, the file can change and gets run-time compiled then its possible that the copy of previous assembly is cached on your system. Reset IIS/web server. And I would also suggest cleaning ASP.NET temporary files in .NET Fx folder under windows.

Comment: @skmasq you should make a new question for your new problem, if your old problem is solve mark this awnser as valid awnser.

Comment: @peer So basically I found out that other programmer made a class with identical class name, and that's why this error was showing up. But one thing, I don't understand why is it showing only now if it was like that all the time.